# $x,y\in L$ tow algebraic element such that $xy,x+y\in K$. $x,y\in K$?

Tags: extension-field

if $L/K$ be a extension field and $x,y\in L$ tow algebraic element over K such that $xy,x+y\in K$. Can we say that $x,y\in K$?

Comment: You can say that $x,y$ belong to some quadratic extension of $K$.

Comment: Note that $x,y$ are the  roots of the quadratic $X^2-(x+y)X+xy$ over $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $K = \mathbf Q$, $L= \mathbf Q[\sqrt 2]$, $x = -y = \sqrt 2$.